# Creating a metro UI like page

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to create a design similar to the Windows 8 metro UI, like in this example image:

[image: Example]

Each of these spans links to one subpage on my server. The URLs, contents and background-images of the tiles are all loaded from a MySQL database, so nothing is hardcoded. I am using **Twitter Bootstrap** for designing purposes.

There are three different possible sizes for each tile:

- large (*span 1*)
- medium (*span 7*)
- small (*span 2*)

I can easily deal with the medium- and small-sized tiles, as each of them only spans over one row. small tiles have the class `col-md-3`, large and medium tiles use `col-md-6`. I can think of the required markup for this kind of design like this:

```
<div class='row'>
    <span class='size-large col-md-6'>span 1</span>
    <span>
        <span class='row'>
            <span class='size-small col-md-3'>span 2</span>
            <span class='size-small col-md-3'>span 3</span>
        </span>
        <span class='row'>
            <span class='size-small col-md-3'>span 4</span>
            <span class='size-small col-md-3'>span 5</span>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
<div class='row'>
    <span class='size-small col-md-3'>span 6</span>
    <span class='size-medium col-md-6'>span 7</span>
    <span class='size-small col-md-3'>span 8</span>
</div>
<div class='row'>
    <span class='row'>
        <span class='size-medium col-md-6'>span 9</span>
    </span>
    <span>
        <span class='size-small col-md-3'>span 11</span>
        <span class='size-small col-md-3'>span 12</span>
    </span>
    <span class='size-large col-md-6'>span 10</span>
</div>
```

Everything's quite easily understandable until now. But here begins the difficult part: Creating the markup **dynamically** after loading the tile's data from the database.

These are the values I have: `$size`, `$name`, `$description`, `$background`.

I started with this:

```
$width = 0;
echo "<div class='row'>";
foreach (Project::getAllTiles() as $i => $project) {
    $thisWidth = 0;
    list($size, $name, $description, $image) =
        array($project['size'], $project['name'], $project['description'], $project['background']);
    $thisWidth = $size == 'small' ? 3 : 6; // Width of this tile
    $width += $thisWidth; // Width of current row
    if ($width > 12) {
        echo "</div><div class='row'>"; // Jump to next row
        $width = 0; // Reset width of row
    }
    echo "<div class='col-md-$thisWidth size-$size'>";
        echo $name; // Placeholder
    echo "</div>";
}
echo "</div>";
```

This works well for small and medium sized tiles. However I can not imagine an easy way to also handle large tiles, which span over two rows. I hope someone can give me a hint on how to do this or some snippets so I can try it myself.

Comment: Do you really want to reinvent the wheel? http://talkslab.github.io/metro-bootstrap/components.html

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I know that there are working metro frameworks out there, however I haven't seen any of these work with multi-row tiles yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After more research I found a bootstrap framework that is capable of exactly what I want to achieve. *Gerald Schneider* [suggested me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24569001/creating-a-metro-ui-like-page#comment38056553_24569001) to use **Metro Bootstrap**, which - based on my tests - wasn't really capable of multi line tiles.

**[Metro UI](http://metroui.org.ua)** however is ([working demo](http://metroui.org.ua/start-screen.html)). I still haven't been able to figure out how to create this markup dynamically via PHP, so I will use the easier already existent Metro UI instead.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done using Metro UI.
Metro UI implementation is described in next section step by step.

**Step 1**

Download Metro-UI-CSS-master zip file from https://github.com/olton/Metro-UI-CSS.
Extract this zip file.After extraction,'Metro-UI-CSS-master'folder will be generated.

**Step 2**

Copy 'Metro-UI-CSS-master' folder into required directory.
I copied it into the css folder of the my project folder
My project folder:-C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\doc\
My css folder:-C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\doc\user\css

After copying '/Metro-UI-CSS-master' into css folder folder structure will look like below.

C:/xampp/htdocs/xampp/doc/user/css/Metro-UI-CSS-master/

**Step 3**

Link Metro-UI framework to our html code.
I copied below code into 'index.tpl'.'index.tpl'is placed in the folder 'C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\doc\user\html' and it worked.

```
<link href="css/Metro-UI-CSS-master/build/css/metro.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/Metro-UI-CSS-master/build/css/metro-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://metroui.org.ua/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="css/Metro-UI-CSS-master/build/js/metro.js"></script>
```

**OR**

```
<link href="http://metroui.org.ua/css/metro.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://metroui.org.ua/css/metro-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://metroui.org.ua/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://metroui.org.ua/js/metro.js"></script>
```

**Complete code**(Sample code to implement metro UI)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta name="description" content="Metro, a sleek, intuitive, and powerful framework for faster and easier web development for Windows Metro Style.">
<meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, JS, JavaScript, framework, metro, front-end, frontend, web development">
<meta name="author" content="Sergey Pimenov and Metro UI CSS contributors">
<link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='../favicon.ico' />
<title>Sample Metro</title>
<link href="css/Metro-UI-CSS-master/build/css/metro.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/Metro-UI-CSS-master/build/css/metro-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://metroui.org.ua/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="css/Metro-UI-CSS-master/build/js/metro.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
<div class="countdown" data-role="countdown" data-days="2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```